# MySQL high cpu load slow quries being logged need help to understand

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to troubleshoot a high load problem on a server, Today for some reason MySQL is taking up excessive CPU time. I have enabled slow-queries and found this query and others similar.

The tables has around 700k rows.

`SELECT SUM( likes ) AS likes, image_id FROM post_files_likes WHERE image_id NOT IN(563593,591800,578109,581180,515832,646310,670601,626185,689090,80019,399472,468198) AND date > DATE_SUB( '2013-08-19' , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) GROUP BY image_id ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 12;`

`

```
mysql> describe post_files_likes
    -> ;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| image_id | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| likes    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date     | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SUM( likes ) AS likes, image_id FROM post_files_likes WHERE image_id NOT IN(563593,591800,578109,581180,515832,646310,670601,626185,689090,80019,399472,468198) AND date > DATE_SUB( '2013-08-19' , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) GROUP BY image_id ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 12;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys       | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_files_likes | range | image_id,image_id_2 | image_id_2 | 4       | NULL | 709885 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (2.92 sec)
```

I have run this query a few times and get anywhere between 0 to 30 seconds.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this query? or is this query taking a long time due to other issues with mysql?

EDIT

```
 SHOW INDEX FROM post_files_likes;
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| post_files_likes |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |      710969 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          0 | image_id   |            1 | image_id    | A         |      355484 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          0 | image_id   |            2 | date        | A         |      710969 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          1 | image_id_2 |            1 | image_id    | A         |      355484 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

EDIT Added indexes

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM post_files_likes;
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| post_files_likes |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |      711181 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          0 | image_id   |            1 | image_id    | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          0 | image_id   |            2 | date        | A         |      711181 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          1 | image_id_2 |            1 | image_id    | A         |      237060 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          1 | likes      |            1 | likes       | A         |         445 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          1 | likes      |            2 | date        | A         |        4709 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| post_files_likes |          1 | likes      |            3 | image_id    | A         |      711181 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing instrinsically wrong with the query - but you forgot to tell us how the indexes are configured.

Optimally this query would use a BTREE index on post_files_likes.date, but there are cases where this won't be used by the DBMS / won't improve the performance (e.g. if the cardinality of the date column is low the DBMS won't use it, a hash based index is very innefficient for looking up ranges of data).

Adding image_id then LIKES to the index (AFTER date) means that the index is covering and the query can be satisfied without reference to the table data. But can a post be liked more than once at exactly the same time?

If you're running this wquery frequently then denormalizing and / or caching the results will help, as (again inferring from context) the data does not appear to be needed in real-time.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have added the output of  SHOW INDEX FROM post_files_likes;` Do you think I should add an index to date? Or does this mean it already has an index?

Comment: Yes you should an index, but not JUST `date`. You should have a BTREE index on (date, image_id [, likes]). And your primary key index on id should be a HASH. You should also review your code to see if the existing image_id and image_id2 indexes are getting used at all.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I have added the indexes and listed above. Can you see if what I have done is right, I have never had to work with indexes before.

Comment: For this query (unless your data is rather skewed) the order should be date, image_id, likes - that's not what you've got here. All other things being equal, fields used in filtering should come before fields added to get covering queries. Fields with higher cardinality *should* come first but given the nature of the query, although image_id has a higher cardinality than date, a negated match means image_id is not effective for lookup (except in the case where it's a covering index) in this case, it would be more effective to put date first.

Comment: Hey thanks, after implementing and index on the fields you said, the load has come right down.  Thanks now i'm off to learn about indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this table indexed?

```
SHOW INDEX FROM post_files_likes;
```

How many rows were returned by this query (without SUM)?

Is your my.cnf optimized for this?

Try to tune parameters for optimal configuration, at least with this: https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

Comment: Hey thanks, I have added the output of SHOW INDEX FROM post_files_likes

Comment: Now it looks fine and i recommend to tune mysql too.

Answer (score 0):

From your query plan:

> `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`

This is going to suck. It's going to use a temporary, on-disk table.

The likely cause of this is that mysql is using the key `image_id_2`, which does *not* include the date, this is because you use `DATE_SUB(...)` instead of a simple comparison. Try precalculating the cutoff date in your code and using `date >= that-date-here`